# If I change old analytics code into universal google analytics code it affect existing Google Analytics reporting?

Tags: google-analytics, digital

I am going to change old analytics code into "Universal google analytics code"  it affect existing Google Analytics reporting or does it just affect Adwords? (I need to remove old code from the website or both codes are needed to present in the website )

I am new to marketing please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you're using ga.js and want to go to analytics.js?

Comment: Currently using : function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
          ga('create', 'xx-xxxxxx-x', 'auto');
          ga('send', 'pageview');

Comment: If you're using that you should already be using UA.

Comment: I want to use google tag manager is this possible with the above code ? like https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7548399?hl=en

Comment: No, if you want to use Google Tag manager you need to have the GTM container tag, here's a quickstart https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart When you have that code on your page, you can use: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107124?hl=en to install GA through GTM

Comment: Sorry , When I generate in dashboard it gives this code but this not verified. <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: xxxxxxx -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-xxxxxxxx"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
 
  gtag('config', 'AW-xxxxxxxxx');
</script>

Comment: You should be generating the container ID from tag manager first, place that on the page. Then use GTM to configure GA and AdWords.

Answer (score 0):

If you replicate your old analytics implementation using the new library it will not affect reporting. I.e. if you are only collecting pageviews, then replacing one code snippet with another is 100% safe.
If there are some custom implemented scripts you will need to rewrite them using new analytics library syntax.

If you are just tracking pageviews - GTM (Google Tag Manager) is an overkill for you.